# .split() не делит строку

Tags: java

есть строка `cbr-coa-dic:Osv_Dt_A_10501$dim-int:Nacz_Inostr_Valyuta_Axis/mem-int:Nacz_Valyuta_Rf_Member`
ее необходимо раздеить по символу $ 
пробовал делить `String[] soch =  f.split( "$");`
но деления не происходит, при том , что заменив на другой символ(допустим d) строка делится нормально.
в чем может быть проблема и как ее можно решить?

Comment: Потому что это регулярка, попробуйте `split("\\$")`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо!
несколько часов понять не мог в чем проблема.....
если напишите как ответ, то приму его)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] soch = f.split("\\$");
```

Согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), первый аргумент метода `split` — это строка, содержащая регулярное выражение, которое ищет куски, по которым будет делиться строка. У регулярных выражений есть свой синтаксис, и знак доллара является частью этого синтаксиса (а также точка, вопросительный знак, скобки и другие символы).

Чтобы доллар воспринимался как просто доллар, а не как часть синтаксиса регулярки, нужно его экранировать, поставив перед ним слэш. Но если просто написать `"\$"`, то это ничего не даст, так как это экранирование на уровне синтаксиса строки Java, а нам надо запихнуть слэш в саму строку, поэтому записываем слэш в экранированном виде: `"\\$"` даст нам строку из двух символов `\$`, которая является регулярным выражением, которое будет искать просто знаки доллара.